# Problem regarding beautiful soup 4 module

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I'm very confused, because this code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  The code's based on the beautiful soup module. I want to know why it works in some circumstances and why it doesn't at other times.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/xrp/"
request = requests.get(url)
content = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

res = soup.find('div', class_=["priceSection"])
price = res.find('div', class_=["priceValue"])
title = res.find('div', class_=["priceTitle"])
result = title.text.replace(price.text,'')
print(result)
```

Comment: What's it doing / not doing? Is there an error?

Comment: File "c:\VSCode Projects\Work\Coins\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    price = res.find('div', class_=["priceValue"])
            ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: It seems that the web page sometimes contains a `div` with class `priceSection` and sometimes not.

Comment: Could you explain me how?

Comment: I don't know why this happens, maybe some mechanism to prevent bots from scraping data or too much requests in short time.

Comment: Do you know how can I make it work all the time?

Comment: What are the exact data that you are trying to extract?

Comment: percentage that is next to the price. You can see it if go by the link

Comment: Can you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76226162/11082237) and printing the value of `content` in the `else` case. You can then check what kind of response you got instead of the HTML you expected

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you learn that the problem comes from `res` being `None`. This happens because the `soup.find('div', class_=["priceSection"])` did not find anything ([this behavior is explicitly documented](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find))

The most obvious cause for your code sometimes working and sometimes not is that the website does not always return the same response to your request.

The simplest (although not the cleanest) fix would be to check that you actually got a result before using it (`if res is not None:`). You will then be able to do something appropriate, like wait a few seconds and retry the request, if you got a `None` result to your `find(...)` call.

If you want a cleaner way to make your code more reliable, you can wrap the request and parsing into a function :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import time

def get_price(currency, max_retries=5, wait_s=2):
    url = f"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{currency}/"
    request = requests.get(url)
    content = request.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    
    res = soup.find('div', class_=["priceSection"])
    if res is not None:
        price = res.find('div', class_=["priceValue"])
        title = res.find('div', class_=["priceTitle"])
        result = title.text.replace(price.text,'')
    elif max_retries > 0:
        print(f"Waiting {wait_s}s before retrying ({max_retries} tries left)")
        time.sleep(wait_s)
        result = get_price(currency, max_retries=max_retries-1, wait_s=wait_s*2)
    else:
        print(f"Could not find a 'div.priceSection' in :\n{content}")
        result = "Error : Max retries exceeded"
    
    return result

print(get_price("xrp"))
```

The site you are scraping (Coinmarketcap) seems to be a Single Page App (SPA) with Server Side Rendering (SSR) on the first load. SSR executes the javascript on the server when you first load the page and directly serves you the rendered HTML. Without SSR, your scraper would need to execute the Javascript itself for it to work.

After testing the code I just provided, it seems like Coinmarketcap disables SSR after you make a burst of requests to it, probably to prevent you from using too much resources on their servers. This does not prevent the page from working in a regular browser since the SPA is still served, but will stop most bots and scrapers such as the simple one from your question. You should try adding a few seconds of delay between each request in order to not trigger the bot detection in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The data is updated in the webpage live by the use of `Javascript`, this seems to be causing the problem.
You can try using [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for this purpose:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/xrp/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bIyrLx')))
print(data.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: It isn't working